# Преобразование Series в dict (словарь)

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть Series **maxBTSID**  который состоит из 2х колонок, полученный из моего DataFrame **sql_huawei_bsc_GEXT3GCELL** по двум значением.
Теперь я хочу преобразовать этот series в словарь, чтобы значения левого столбца были ключами, а значения правого содержимым.

*

```
maxBTSID = sql_huawei_bsc_GEXT3GCELL.groupby('BSC')['Huawei_BSC_3GBTSID'].max()
sql_huawei_bsc_GEXT3GCELL['max'] = sql_huawei_bsc_GEXT3GCELL.groupby('BSC')['Huawei_BSC_3GBTSID'].transform('max')
```

- 

вывод **maxBTSID** в данный момент

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [Series.to_dict()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html).

Пример:

```
In [537]: s = pd.Series([1,2,3], index=list("abc"))

In [538]: s
Out[538]:
a    1
b    2
c    3
dtype: int64

In [539]: res = s.to_dict()

In [540]: res
Out[540]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```